# How can I serialize bash commands?

Tags: bash

I just want to do a simple greeting:

I tried:

```
echo "Welcome " + whoami

echo "Welcome " . whoami
```

and finally

```
echo "Welcome "; whoami
```

came close but it added a return character between the statements like this

```
Welcome 
user
```

I want the output to be:

```
Welcome user
```

In general I want this to work:

```
#run
run(){
    rc
    show
    pwd
    a=whomai
    b=pwd
    c=timestamp
    echo "Welcome $a, you are in $b, and the time is $c"
}

run
```

Comment: Just use a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution): `a=$(whoami)`, etc.

Comment: Also, consider using `"$PWD"` rather than running `pwd` from your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` emits a newline at the end of its output, and the usual ways to avoid this (with `-n`) are not required to be supported by the POSIX standard ([POSIX leaves echo behavior undefined with a wide array of inputs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), making it undesirable for use with non-constant strings). Use `printf` instead:

```
printf 'Welcome '; whoami
```

That said, if you want to assign output of a command to a variable, use [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
a=$(whoami)
printf '%s\n' "Welcome, $a"
```

This can also be inlined:

```
printf '%s\n' "Welcome, $(whoami)"
```

---

Thus:

```
run() {
    local a b c          # declare locals to avoid polluting namespace outside function

    a=${USER:-$(whoami)} # only call $(whoami) if $USER is unset
    b=$PWD               # more efficient than $(pwd), which runs a subshell
    c=$(date)            # for bash 4, this could be instead: printf -v c '%(%T)T' 0
                         # ...which would avoid calling external commands, and thus also
                         # ...be more efficient.
    printf '%s\n' "Welcome $a, you are in $b, and the time is $c"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Welcome $(whoami)"
```

should do the trick.